# How to check the sign of a cell and then copy and paste it to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I have a column of numbers and want to go through each cell to check if the number is positive, or negative. After determining if a number is positive, or negative I want to copy and paste that number into a new table on a new sheet separating the positive and negative values.

I used a nested if statement to do this originally but instead of getting a list of 20 positive numbers, and 20 negative numbers from my total of 40 numbers I got a list of 20 positive numbers with 20 false conditions in my new positive only table (same thing with the negative).

I would like to pull the positive and negative values without duplicating them, or getting the false condition of the if statement in my new table.

The last thing I have been trying to implement is having this code search through my column of numbers instead of a fixed range so in the future I can add numbers and the new positive/negative tables will automatically generate the additional numbers.

I am fairly new to VBA and coding in general so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Olek!

---

My code pretty much follows the Macro code:

```
Sub Variance()
'
' Variance Macro
'

'
Range("F2:F60").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Macro").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1:A60").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$60").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
Range("A3:A60").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Bullseye").Select
Range("AH3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AH:AH").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
Sheets("Macro").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$60").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
Range("A2:A59").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Bullseye").Select
Range("AK3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This code gets the job done but I wanted to change it so that I could have code run that will auto generate all my data in the same way but without having a fixed range. Additionally, I have to delete all the data that this macro fills if I want to run it again.

Basically just trying to cut down the number of steps so that this sheet is fully automated as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: please add you code

Comment: Hard to see what the issue is without seeing the code.  Please edit your post to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a variable.  In this case, the variable RowNum finds row number for the last value in column F.  You can then substitute the variable RowNum for the number 60 in each place in your code, making your ranges dynamic like this:

```
    Dim RowNum As Integer

    RowNum = Sheets("Macro").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F2:F" & RowNum).Select    
    '...
    Range("A2:A" & RowNum).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to avoid all `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern design which is 99,99% unnecessary and switch to fully qualified range references

furthermore you don't need any "intermediate" sheet as your "macro" since you can filter data directly in place

```
Option Explicit

Sub Variance()
    With Worksheets("numbersSheet") '<--| reference your data worksheet (change "numbersSheet" to your actual sheet with numbers name)
        With Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "F" range from row 1 (header) down to last not empty row
            FilterAndWrite .Cells, ">=0", Worksheets("Bullseye").Range("AH3") '<--| filter positive or zero values and write them from Worksheets("Bullseye").Range("AH3") downwards
            FilterAndWrite .Cells, "<0", Worksheets("Bullseye").Range("AK3") '<--| filter negative values and write them from Worksheets("Bullseye").Range("AK3") downwards
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub FilterAndWrite(sourceRng As Range, criterium As String, targetRng As Range)
    With sourceRng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criterium
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other than header
            .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '<--| copy filtered cell skipping header
            targetRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<--| paste values in passed target range
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Olek, did you get through it?